# Django Admin does not work after deployment Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-forms, django-admin, django-login

After deploying my application the admin of the website does not work. I am able to use the website, create an account and do all the crud, but the admin does not work.

1 - I created the superuser with

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

2 - I deployed and tried to access the admin
https://djangotodowoo.herokuapp.com/admin

Although, every time that I try to access this page it redirects to:
https://djangotodowoo.herokuapp.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/

I am not sure if that's the problem, but it's a hint at least.

This is happening because I have on my settings.py the following line

```
LOGIN_URL = '/login'
```

That checks if someone is trying to access a page without login and redirects to the login page.

---

I am not sure what the problem actually is, any ideas on how to solve the issue?

Thank you very much folks!

Comment: We need more information from you because "...does not work tells us little about the problem": (1) I guess you created the superuser on heroku not locally? (2) What's wrong with the login address? You do not tell us. Better use `LOGIN_URL = '/login/'`.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that everything was working locally, the reason I was not able to log into the admin with my admin account is that I have to create a superuser on the Heroku side as well.

The solution was:

**Create Heroku Super User**

```
heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Comment: If you want to automate this process in future, you can add a custom migration in Django that creates the superuser. Just remind to change the password at same point if you don't want to use the one hardcoded in your migration.